# How to return a HashMap from a list of objects?

Tags: java, hashmap

Currently, I am trying to return a `HashMap`. With a parameter of an `ArrayList` that has 50 or more entries.

```
public static HashMap<String, Doctor> getDoctorHash(ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList) {

    HashMap<String, Doctor> hm = new HashMap<>();

    for(Doctor doctor : doctorList) {
        hm.put(doctor.getId(), doctor);
    }

    return hm;
}
```

I am passing the Id as the key and doctor object as the value..

My `Doctor` class is simple:

```
public class Doctor {
    private String firstName, lastName, id;

    public Doctor(String firstName, String lastName, String id) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.id = id;
    }
    //getter and setters etc.
}
```

Comment: change employeeList to doctorList and Doctor.size() to doctorList.size()

Comment: A [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) defines a mapping, e.g. in your example you would query with a `String` and get a `Doctor` in return. This is why [`put(K key, V value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) needs two parameters. Maybe you want to use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)?

Comment: Well, what should be your key? The point of a Map is to associate a value with a `Key`, which in this case you've specified to be `String`. So you need a `String` value which associates to a specific `Doctor` (aka `put("Bob", /* some doctor */);` would allow using `get("Bob")` to retrieve that instance back

Comment: You need to adopt a rational process here. Your code doesn't compile. Understand why by *reading* the error messages, not ignoring them. Try to make sense of them. You don't know what a HashMap is and how it works, then *read* its documentation. The documentation is too obscure, then google for "Java HashMap tutorial", and *read*.

Comment: First off, your code misses some parentheses (it should be `.getFirstName()`). Also, I would recommend using `id` as a key, as IDs are usually more unique than a first name. Otherwise, your question lacks a clear problem statement. If you don't tell us what you are having problems with, we **cannot** help you.

Comment: Also, `Doctor.size()` should be `doctorList.size()`.

Comment: Hi all, I used the ID as my key and passed in emp as the value! currently, i am able to pass my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do it this way, (you could use a Java8 stream and `filter` the list for first names), but you are close.

```
public static HashMap<String, Doctor> getDoctorHash(ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList) {

    HashMap<String, Doctor> hm = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < doctorList.size(); i++) {
        hm.put(doctorList.get(i).getFirstName(), doctorList.get(i));
    }

    return hm;
}
```

Or, more simply

```
public static HashMap<String, Doctor> getDoctorHash(ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList) {

    HashMap<String, Doctor> hm = new HashMap<>();

    for(Doctor d : doctorList) {
        hm.put(d.getFirstName(), d);
    }

    return hm;
}
```

Then, you have to `Doctor d = doctorMap.get("firstname")` for some `firstname`

Comment: It turns out that the problem persists; when one tries to get the value of one of the created HashMap's keys, the console returns a NullPointerException error. I don't have the slightest idea of what the reason behind this could be, nevertheless.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you have non-null Doctor objects in the list, then nothing throws NPE.

Comment: In the first snippet of code that I implemented in my answer, inside of the definition of the getDoctorHash() function, there's a System.out.println() statement that is used for assuring that the Doctor object is not null at the beginning. In spite of this, a NPE is thrown later.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a solution, but something that can be used for deriving one from it**

Due to that you haven't stated what the output of the console was, I'm not able to know which specific errors you have.

Nevertheless, I created the following code for giving myself an idea:

```
public class StartingPoint {

    static String[] doctorNames = {"Potato", "Chocolate", "Something", "Name", "Unnamed"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {            

        ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<>(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            doctorList.add(new Doctor(doctorNames[i], doctorNames[i] + " last name", String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        HashMap<String, Doctor> someHashMap = getDoctorHash(doctorList);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("The ID of the doctor number " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + " is: ");
            System.out.println(someHashMap.get(doctorNames[i]).getId());
        }
    }

    public static HashMap<String, Doctor> getDoctorHash(ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList) {

        HashMap<String, Doctor> hm = new HashMap<>();

        for(Doctor doctor : doctorList) {
            System.out.println(doctor);
            hm.put(doctor.getId(), doctor);
        }

        return hm;
    }

}
```

It turns out that the compiler acts as if there weren't such a thing as a `Doctor` object being the value of an item's ID (that acts as a key). Nevertheless, it can be seen that when one tries to print out the location in memory of each one of the `Doctor` items of the `ArrayList` passed to the `getDoctorHash()` function in its definition, there are no problems at all.
I don't have the slightest idea about what the reason behind of this is.

But, if instead of using the `Doctor` objects as values we use one of the `String`s that can be obtained by making use of one of its methods, everything turns out well:

```
public class StartingPoint {

    static String[] doctorNames = {"Potato", "Chocolate", "Something", "Name", "Unnamed"};


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<>(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            doctorList.add(new Doctor(doctorNames[i], doctorNames[i] + " last name", String.valueOf(i)));
        }

        HashMap<String, String> someHashMap = getDoctorHash(doctorList);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("The first name of the doctor number " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + " is: ");
            System.out.println(someHashMap.get(String.valueOf(i)));
        }
    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> getDoctorHash(ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList) {

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

        for(Doctor doctor : doctorList) {
            hm.put(doctor.getId(), doctor.getFirstName());
        }

        return hm;
    }

}
```